# repo manifest . fatal: manifest 'default.xml' not available

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-source, repo

I have a repo manifest file default.xml . However, when I execute

```
repo init -u <MYREPOURL> -b branch1
```

I get this error

> fatal: manifest 'default.xml' not available

> fatal: duplicate path . in <CURRENTDIR>/.repo/manifests/default.xml

what could be the issue. I tried a lot of things but it did not help. Below is manifest with actual name of repos and folders changed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote name="repo1" fetch="git://git.repo1.com" />
  <remote name="repo2" fetch="git://git.repo2.com"/>
  <remote name="repo3" fetch="git://git.repo3.com"/>
  <remote name="repo4" fetch="git://git.repo4.com"/>
  <project name="folder1/folder2" path="meta-group1" groups="group1" remote="repo1" revision="branch1"/>
  <project name="folder1/folder3" path="meta-group12" groups="group1" remote="repo1" revision="branch1"/>
  <project name="folder1/folder4" path="folder5/folder6" groups="group1" remote="repo1" revision="branch1"/>
  <project name="folder1/folder8" path="meta-projectx" groups="group1" remote="repo1" revision="branch1"/>
  <project name="folder9" path="." groups="group2" remote="repo2" revision="branch1"/>
  <project name="meta-abc" path="." groups="group2" remote="repo3" revision="branch1"/>
  <project name="meta-pqr" path="." groups="group2" remote="repo3" revision="branch1"/>
  <project name="meta-xyz" path="." groups="group3" remote="repo4" revision="branch1"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

We typically run into this issue when reusing an AOSP checkout directory to switch to a different branch or version of the code base. Existing files from the previous build and pre-build steps can interfere with the repo init and repo sync commands.

> fatal: manifest 'default.xml' not available

The above error is thrown by the `Sync` method of class `Project` under `.repo/repo/project.py`, if it encounters a `ManifestParseError` while parsing the manifest xml which has the default name of `default.xml`. Because the code was not able to parse the xml, it reports that the manifest default.xml is not available, which can be a little misleading for the user of the repo command.

The more relevant error for debugging is the second one, which prints the specific `ManifestParseError`. In case of this question it is

> fatal: duplicate path . in /.repo/manifests/default.xml

The parse operation includes some of the other manifests under `.repo/local_manifests`. These are typically populated during the pre-build steps like `breakfast`. Paths in one of these manifest files could be conflicting with the ones in `default.xml`.

So one could try the following options

1. Check the files under `.repo/local_manifests` and identify the bad one and comment out the bad line and try the `repo init` command again
2. Move all the manifest files under `.repo/local_manifests` out of the checkout tree and try the `repo init` command again

In my case my bad line was in `.repo/local_manifests/roomservice.xml` so I moved the file out of the tree and `repo init` worked.

Here is another [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567212/2130670) which might help.